# jquery plugin producing console error

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to use this jquery plugin to create a multi level mobile menu. http://tympanus.net/Development/ResponsiveMultiLevelMenu/index2.html

However, I've tried multiple times to set it up on my page, and it produces a console error that says $(...).dlmenu is not a function. Any suggestions?

Live page where error is occurring: http://www.localalarm.com/nav

Comment: Looks like your javascript file is not loading on your page. It is commented out.
<!--<script src="/js/localalarm/jquery.dlmenu.modernizr.custom.js"></script>-->

Comment: That script isn't required, I commented it out because I replaced it with /js/localalarm/modernizr.custom.js, which is active below.